# How to generate a table (matrix) with rows from one table and columns from another?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables [item,branch,assign].

### Item table

id,item_name

### Branch table

id,branch_name

### Assign table

id,item_id,branch_id,qty

So, I want the below.

```
|        | branch1 | branch 2 | branch 3 | branch 4 |
|--------|---------|----------|----------|----------|
| item 1 | 1       | 2        | 0        | 3        |
| item 2 | 3       | 2        | 0        | 0        |
| item 3 | 0       | 0        | 3        | 2        |
```

How can I do that? Please instruct me how to do?

Thanks